# Automatically Add 30 min to logout time column SQL

Tags: oracle

I have a table with id, login, and logout.

id -> number

login -> date

logout -> date

The employee has to login but they do not have to logout. The logout time will just be + 30 min added to the login time. How can I achieve this so the logout column is automatically updated for that time?

Example:

Employee logins in at 1:00 PM. Their logout time will be 1:30 PM.

Comment: At what point do you decide - what triggers the decision - that you need to record this 'default' logout time?  As opposed to determining that the worker hasn't logged out because he is still working?

Comment: Or, is the "logout" really more of a session expiration?

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into mytable (id, login, logout) values (mytable_seq.nextval, sysdate, sysdate + 30/1440);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, add an *interval*:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate right_now,
  2         sysdate + interval '30' minute half_an_hour_later
  3  from dual;

RIGHT_NOW           HALF_AN_HOUR_LATER
------------------- -------------------
05.08.2019 21:31:40 05.08.2019 22:01:40

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `virtual column` concept here to automatically calculate the value as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE YOUR_TABLE_NAME (
    ID       NUMBER,
    LOGIN    DATE,
        LOGOUT   DATE GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( LOGIN + INTERVAL '30' MINUTE ) VIRTUAL
);

INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE_NAME (
    ID,
    LOGIN
) VALUES (
    1,
    TO_DATE('01-01-2019 01:00', 'DD-MM-RRRR HH24:MI')
);

SELECT
    *
FROM
    YOUR_TABLE_NAME;
```

Output:

```
        ID LOGIN               LOGOUT             
---------- ------------------- -------------------
         1 01-01-2019 01:00:00 01-01-2019 01:30:00
```

This will add 30 minutes to the login to calculate the logout column and you do not need to take any specific external action for it.

Cheers!!